# Get product outside magento directory without knowing ID

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I've got a CSV full of SKU's that I need to load outside the Magento directory to make some changes.

So far I have this:

```
require_once('bla/bla/../../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(15186);
$productid = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('thatsku');
$product2->load($productid);
var_dump($product1);
var_dump($product2);
```

In this case, $product1 returns the product as expected, but $product2 returns `bool(false)`.
Same thing happens when I try this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
var_dump ($_product);
```

$product also returns as `bool(false)` here.

Any idea on what's going on?

EDIT: Sorry I'm dumb. There was no SKU in the database even thought I could've sweared I added it for testing sake. This code works.

Comment: Try with `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', trim($sku));
var_dump ($_product);`

Comment: Returns `null` in that case.

Comment: Are you sure there's a product with that sku? At the same time `$product2->load($productid);` this line seems to be wrong

Comment: Oh damn. Could have sweared I added it for testing sake. Went to double check and it wasn't there. Not sure what happened but that was a the problem. I feel dumb now! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

You can also filter product via `loadByAttribute()`

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $product_sku);

var_dump($product);
```

try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 $productid = $model->getIdBySku('tomato');
    $prod = $model->load($productid);
    var_dump($prod);
    exit;
```

> Note: Check whether is there a product for the given sku

Comment: Oh damn. Could have sweared I added it for testing sake. Went to double check and it wasn't there. Not sure what happened but that was a the problem. I feel dumb now! Thanks for the heads up!